How to prevent leaves from going into the water drains of a flat roof?
I have a flat roof with rainwater drains like this:



Having oak trees next to the house, a lot of leaves can go on the roof and potentially block the stormwater pipes.
I am looking for a way to prevent the leaves from going into the rainwater drain such as a grid or something else. Knowing that I don't want to damage the flat roof membrane.
Thanks for your help.

Make a grill - they even sell them for gutters.

@SolarMike  Would not a grill/screen be worst for that use.  Right now it seems the rain water can wash the leaves right out/through, but with a grill it will hold the leaves.

@crip659 "wash the leaves right out" - right down to the next blockage point. Which is usually much harder to get to. One reason why many flow systems like drains on the roads have grills fitted. Just need something called maintenance - best is regular...

@crip659 "out/though" did you mean "through"?

@crip659 Indeed, as Solar Mike said, I prefer the leaves not to go any further, because then they would go into the drain pipes.

@Alain if you make it big, think like a supermarket shopping trolley, then it may need less cleaning compared to a small grill just the size of the opening...

The fix needs to be beyond that. Not at the parapet of the roof where it will be a trap. There is no picture of where the rain goes on the other side, but I imagine it is a scupper. If it is, a screen or grate needs to go over that so the leaves will pass over it and the rain will go through. The opening in the roof wall (parapet) is plenty big. Again, don't look there for answers. The only time that will clog is if a limb happens o fall right there.

In U.S. English, the device is known as a grille, which may help with internet searches for the appropriate contrivance.

Has this actually plugged or is this preventative?  15"x9" seems really big to plug.  You could point a spray hose at it to get the leaves moving through if they get hung up.

What does the other side of those holes look like? I would want the leaves to get off the roof, then maybe divert them before getting into a gutter or downspout.

I had an idea for mesh screening with razor sharp grid years ago.   Would sell it for ground drains, shower drains, gutters...   shark tank idea.    I was going to get it patented.    Until I talked to a friend that was a lawyer and was going to help me find a patent attorney.   He said...   if you ever sell this product I will be hired to sue you because someone reached their hand down a drain or gutter and it is cut up...

We need pics further downstream from the hole in the parapet.  Do you want to keep the leaves on the roof?  Is is easier to clean them from there than another location further downstream?  Finally, the surefire way to solve your problem is to cut down the offending trees...

Don't!
Anything you do to keep leaves out of that hole will result in the leaves clogging the hole.  Instead, you need to do some other things:

Remove the leaves frequently
Make the hole, and the downspout, bigger, and arrange the other end of it in such a way that the water and leaves can go separate ways.  For example, terminate the pipe a foot above a small gravel-filled dry well.  There are probably better ways ... but that's a good separate question.
If the trees are overhanging the roof, cut them back every few years.

I can't think of a reasonable way to separate the water and leaves while they are still on the roof, but just for fun, an unreasonable one would be a bunch of big fans, calibrated so they blow the leaves off the roof but still allow the water to flow to the spout.  Whatever you come up with has to seem more sensible than using a broom.
[ Additional idea ] IDK maybe this is nuts, maybe the shopping cart idea is better but .... 1) Put a reasonably small grill around the opening.  2) Secure a 2 inch pipe from ground level, up and over the parapet near the drain. At ground level, you attach a leaf blower from time to time.  At roof level, you secure the end of the pipe where the  blower will clear the leaves from the grill.  And install a little web cam up there so you can see if it's working.  You could probably even train some brands of cheap webcam to recognize that the leaves have blocked the pipe and notify your phone.

The roof was recently done (so still under warranty), enlarging the hole is not an option. A good part of the trees do not belong to me, and even if they are at a certain distance, spread their leaves on the roof.
I am aware that installing a grid or something like will require me to clean it regularly, but I think it is better than having to unclog a pipe buried under the construction.
However, I note the idea of ​​gravel to separate the water from the leaves.

Ah, if the pipe continues underground rather than dumping water on the ground, my #2 is not a good idea.   You COULD create a buffer.  Cut the pipe and have it dump into a pit/well of some kind, and connect THAT to the existing underground pipe.  And IDK where you are but in most places you can cut a neighbor's tree if it overhangs your property, and you SHOULD do where it directly overhangs a flat roof.  It won't eliminate the problem entirely but will make it much better.  And they're oaks! You'll almost entirely eliminate acorns falling on your roof.

If he farmed millipedes on the roof, they eat dead leaves....    Mass screening (stucco mesh) could cover the roof... not buying a house with a flat roof...   Little keebler elves with little knives to chop up the leaves...

@DMoore ya they eat dead leaves then crawl up your drain in the shower.  Bad enough his roof is covered in acorns, he needs more vermin magnets?   :)

There are a number of options

You can buy some ready made grills, look in a plumbing shop
You can make one up from plastic coated wire from a garden centre.  You can spot glue it in half a dozen places.
You can use brushes made for gutters (called hedgehogs around here).  Grab a few and just pile them in front.
Assuming it goes to a down pipe, there are leaf slides available, again look at a plumbing shop.


You missed the suggestion of making it big...

Don't
Anything you do to keep leaves on the roof will also keep a certain amount of water, which will bring its own problems:

A few millimeters may not sound like much, but a few millimeters of stagnant water with leaves/dirt mixed in is an ideal breeding ground for mosquitoes.
Humid and dark (shade) is a breeding ground for moss/mold.
It's a roof, not a pool, I wouldn't be that confident in keeping water there for prolonged period of times.

By blocking the outflow, you're creating a huge maintenance burden for yourself, and any time you fall behind on that maintenance, you'll be inviting bigger troubles.
Leaves are relatively small, if you block leaves, you'll also block small branches, the odd dead bird/rodent, etc... and those will clog the hole a lot more, leading to more water being retained. The hole is big because it was sized so that bigger things than leaves would not accidentally clog it.
Do
Instead, you need to separate water from debris (water, dirt, ...) after they leave the roof (free cleaning!) and before they reach the underground pipe.
It's hard to tell from your picture but there seems to be a gutter installed on the other side of the hole. If so, then you have two points:

As mentioned, a gravel pit at the base of the gutter drainpipe and prior to the underground pipe is ideal. It's at ground level so you can easily keep an eye on it and clean it, no ladder required. A few plastic chains hanging from inside the drainpipe to the pit will help curb splashing if you made it a bit too high.
Second best is a mesh at the top of the gutter drainpipe, where the gutter goes into it. Less ideal because you need a ladder to inspect it and clear it, but worst case if you forget is that the gutter overflows, which is readily visible and a sign you need to get up there at the first opportunity.


Grab a few bricks and some mortar, use them to make a portable arch, put a grill on the arch if needed, and place that arch in-front of the hole. Friction and weight will be enough to hold it in place and you can remove it when needed. I have done this personally in a case where it made sense.
Regardless of what you do, you need to sweep the roof regularly, especially when heavy or prolonged rain is predicted make sure that your roof and drains are clear.
